# UV editor - Mirror modifier not working on all faces of cube

Tags: uv, windows

I'm working with the UV mapping editor for the first time and there's something fundamental that I'm not understanding. I want to map an image texture to all faces of a cube so it reads correctly on all faces. I started with the front face, Unwrapped the texture, then used the mirror modifiers to fix the orientation. Works great. However, when I select the other faces, unwrap the texture, the mirror modifiers have no effect; mirror modifiers only seem to work on the front face. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 2.93.5 Windows 10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The difference between the faces was that for the top and sides I hadn't selected the image texture's corner points before applying the mirror transformations. Now all is working great!